# Index Sheet for Hyperlinks of all sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code to create an Index sheet the provides a list of hyperlinks to the all the sheets in the workbooks, plus adding the colour of the tab next to it.

The hyperlinks section is working, but not the colour.
It looks like it starts to work, but when it finishes looping through, cell B2 is just filled black with the border - NB: on the workbook I'm running it on, sheet colours are a combination of blue, green & grey.

I've copied in the full module for reference - the colour section at the bottom, as apparent.

```
Sub CreateIndexSheet()
    Dim indexSheet As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult
    
    ' Check if Index sheet exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Set indexSheet = Worksheets("Index")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' If Index sheet exists, ask user for confirmation
    If Not indexSheet Is Nothing Then
        answer = MsgBox("Index sheet already exists. Do you want to clear it and continue?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "Confirmation")
        
        ' If user chooses No, exit the macro
        If answer = vbNo Then Exit Sub
        
        ' Clear the Index sheet
        indexSheet.Cells.Clear
    Else
        ' If Index sheet doesn't exist, create it
        Set indexSheet = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
        indexSheet.Name = "Index"
    End If
    
    ' Loop through all sheets in the workbook
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ' Add hyperlink to each sheet in Index sheet in column C
        indexSheet.Hyperlinks.Add _
            Anchor:=indexSheet.Cells(indexSheet.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0), _
            Address:="", _
            SubAddress:="'" & ws.Name & "'!A1", _
            TextToDisplay:=ws.Name
        
        ' Make column B 20 pixels wide
        indexSheet.Cells(indexSheet.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).ColumnWidth = 20
        
        ' Highlight the cell in column B with the same color as the corresponding sheet with white borders
        indexSheet.Cells(indexSheet.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Interior.Color = tabColor
        indexSheet.Cells(indexSheet.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Borders.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Next ws
End Sub
```

I have tried re-prompting ChatGPT for fixes, and multiple attempts have still not worked - find below 2x exmaples of suggested fixes:

Fix v1

```
    ' Get RGB color of the sheet's tab
    tabColor = ws.Tab.Color
    
    ' Highlight the cell in column B with the same color as the corresponding sheet with white borders
    With indexSheet.Cells(indexSheet.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        .Interior.Color = tabColor
        .Borders.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End With
```

Fix v2

```
    ' Get RGB color of the sheet's tab
    tabColor = ws.Tab.Color
    
    ' Highlight the cell in column B with the same color as the corresponding sheet with white borders
    With indexSheet.Cells(indexSheet.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        .Interior.Color = tabColor
        .Borders.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End With
```

Comment: Is your "gray" the default tab color?

Comment: No, its 217/217/217

Answer (score 0):

The cells in column B don't contain a value. `.End(xlUp)` will not distinguish between empty cells with formatting applied. Use `Offset` from column C to add the appropriate formatting to column B.

```
    ' Loop through all sheets in the workbook
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        With indexSheet
            Dim anchorCell As Range
            Set anchorCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            
            ' Add hyperlink to each sheet in Index sheet in column C
            .Hyperlinks.Add _
                Anchor:=anchorCell, _
                Address:="", _
                SubAddress:="'" & ws.Name & "'!A1", _
                TextToDisplay:=ws.Name
        End With
        
        ' Make column B 20 pixels wide
        anchorCell.Offset(, -1).ColumnWidth = 20
        
        ' Highlight the cell in column B with the same color as the corresponding sheet with white borders
        anchorCell.Offset(, -1).Interior.Color = ws.Tab.Color
        anchorCell.Offset(, -1).Borders.Color = vbWhite
    Next ws
```

Note that for tabs showing the default color, `.Tab.Color` returns `False`, which when assigned to `.Interior.Color` gives you black. A quick workaround might be to use `VarType` and assign a "default" color.

```
If VarType(ws.Tab.Color) <> vbBoolean Then
    Dim tabColor As Long
    tabColor = ws.Tab.Color
Else
    tabColor = RGB(217, 217, 217) ' Default color here
End If

anchorCell.Offset(, -1).Interior.Color = tabColor
anchorCell.Offset(, -1).Borders.Color = vbWhite
```